# Is there a way I can make an ASP.NET MVC web app execute queries on SQL Server when a date column in a table <= current date

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My question is a mess, but what I mean is basically this: let's say I have a table called `EXECUTELATER` (in my SQL Server database for my app) and I have a column called `DATE`. I want to execute queries every time a row/rows in that table has `DATE <= current system time`, do something with the data, put some data in another table and delete this row from the table `EXECUTELATER`.

One thing in my mind is to create another simple app logged with another user to query every millisecond and check if there is a `DATE` matching, but that sounds absurd.

Is there a way I can do this within the web app? Can anyone suggest me a smart way I can make this work? I don't mind if I have to work with full SQL date format or store the date in long type, work with the web app, create a new application for that use, use something in SQL Server itself or whatever.

Again sorry for the badly structured question, I'm not sure how to put this together. Thank you for checking!

Comment: Sounds like you need to use trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use triggers like :

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[TrgX]
ON  [dbo].[EXECUTELATER]
AFTER UPDATE,insert
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
update [dbo].[tblx]
set [columnx] = x
    from inserted i
    inner join [dbo].[tblx] p on i.[Relatedcoulumn] = p.Relatedcoulumn
    where i.[Date] >= getdate()
   END
```